# Notifico cambios en el adaptador de un listview y solo me añade el primero

Tags: java, android, android-listview

Estoy tratando de cargar un ListView con nombres de jugadores que introduce el usuario. My layout activity_torneo.xml es el siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#f4f4f9"
tools:ignore="DisableBaselineAlignment"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="@string/mesa"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/borde"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/borde">
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rbseis"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/seis"/>
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rbnueve"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/nueve"/>
        </RadioGroup>
        <Space
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="@string/jugadores"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/borde"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/nombrejugador"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="@string/hintnombrejugador"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bAnyadir"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/añadir"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:textColor="@color/white"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listviewjugadores"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Y en la clase java selecciono el adaptador y al introducir un nombre de jugador y pulsar el botón añadir, se  añade el jugador introducido al adaptador y se notifican los cambios.

```
package com.quizandguide.dealerassistant;

import android.graphics.Color; 
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Torneo extends AppCompatActivity {
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private ArrayList<String> jugadores;
EditText nombreJugadorAnyadir;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_torneo);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    toolbar.setBackground(colorDrawable);
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    RadioButton rbSeis = findViewById(R.id.rbseis);
    rbSeis.setChecked(true);
    RadioButton rbNueve = findViewById(R.id.rbnueve);
    Button btnAnyadirJugador = findViewById(R.id.bAnyadir);
    nombreJugadorAnyadir = findViewById(R.id.nombrejugador);
    nombreJugadorAnyadir.clearFocus();
    ListView lvJugadores = findViewById(R.id.listviewjugadores);
    jugadores = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, jugadores);
    lvJugadores.setAdapter(adapter);
    btnAnyadirJugador.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        int maxJugadoresMesa = 0;
        if (rbSeis.isChecked()) {
            maxJugadoresMesa = 6;
        } else {
            maxJugadoresMesa = 9;
        }
        if (jugadores.size()<maxJugadoresMesa) {
            String nombreJugador = nombreJugadorAnyadir.getText().toString();
            jugadores.add(nombreJugador);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            nombreJugadorAnyadir.setText("");
        } else {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ya ha seleccionado el máximo de jugadores", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }

    });
}
}
```

El comportamiento esperado sería que añadiera hasta seis jugadores, pero solo me añade el primero y los siguientes no. Lo curioso es que haciendo Logs registra que jugadores.size va creciendo hasta el límite seis, pero en la pantalla solo se muestra el primer jugador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0):

El problema se debe a esta evaluacion , el valor de `jugadores.size()` puede ser igual o mayor que `maxJugadoresMesa` al inicio:

```
     if (jugadores.size()<maxJugadoresMesa) {
```

Como soluciòn, puedes declarar una variable como contador:

```
private int contador = 0;
```

ahora usa esta variable para detectar cada clic y realizar la evaluaciòn:

```
btnAnyadirJugador.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        int maxJugadoresMesa = 0;
        if (rbSeis.isChecked()) {
            maxJugadoresMesa = 6;
        } else {
            maxJugadoresMesa = 9;
        }
        //if (jugadores.size()<maxJugadoresMesa) {
          if (contador < maxJugadoresMesa) {
            String nombreJugador = nombreJugadorAnyadir.getText().toString();
            jugadores.add(nombreJugador);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            nombreJugadorAnyadir.setText("");
         
            contador++; //incrementa variable.
        } else {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ya ha seleccionado el máximo de jugadores", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();

            contador = 0; //Reinicia contador. 
        }

    });
```